# Finding out existing Webhooks IDs on Trello

Tags: node.js, webhooks, trello

I've added webhooks using Trello's API ([Node JS package](https://github.com/adunkman/node-trello)).
How do I get the current webhooks or how do I get an existing webhook ID?

Could'nt find a way through the API:
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/webhook

[Here](https://developers.trello.com/apis/webhooks) it says that:

> There are three ways to delete webhooks.
>
> 1. Using the DELETE route on webhooks
>    DELETE [https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks/[WEBHOOK_ID]?key=[APPLICATION_KEY]&token=[USER_TOKEN]](https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks/%5BWEBHOOK_ID%5D?key=%5BAPPLICATION_KEY%5D&token=%5BUSER_TOKEN%5D)
> 2. If the webhook request from Trello, when POSTing to the callbackURL, receives an HTTP 410 Gone response, the webhook will be deleted.
> 3. If the token that the webhook is bound to is revoked or expires, then the webhook will be deleted

First method required the ID, second method requires me to take down the server everytime I want to erase a webhook and third is not better. Any idea how to get the IDs?

Answer (score 12):

Here is the API request to get all of the webhooks that have been created by the application:

```
GET https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/tokens?webhooks=true&key=[APPLICATION_KEY]&token=[USER_TOKEN]
```

Relevant Section of the [Trello API Documentation /1/members/[id]/tokens](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/member#get-1-members-idmember-or-username-tokens) listed below:

GET /1/members/[idMember or username]/tokenslink
Required permissions: read, own, account

> Arguments
>
> - `filter` *(optional)*
>
>   - Default: `all`
>   - Valid Values: One of: `all`, `none`
> - `webhooks` *(optional)*
>
>   - Default: `false`
>   - Valid Values: One of: `true`, `false`

Also, note that *me* is used as the *idMember or Username*

> Note: If you specify *me* as the username, this call will respond as if you had supplied the username associated with the supplied token

See [Trello API documentation /1/members/me](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/member#get-1-members-idmember-or-username)

Here is a sample JSON response I get:

```
{
"id": "568d40cc3aa021f1b3602ea0",
"identifier": "Server Token",
"idMember": "562d50bc3aa020f1b3602ec0",
"dateCreated": "2016-05-30T22:01:15.721Z",
"dateExpires": null,
"permissions": [
  {
    "idModel": "562d50bc3aa071f1b3602ec6",
    "modelType": "Member",
    "read": true,
    "write": true
  },
  {
    "idModel": "*",
    "modelType": "Board",
    "read": true,
    "write": true
  },
  {
    "idModel": "*",
    "modelType": "Organization",
    "read": true,
    "write": true
  }
],
"webhooks": [
  {
    "id": "5675a0a8159fbeef4b796da3",
    "description": "Feature Requests Board",
    "idModel": "55a1176a0b620663da985753",
    "callbackURL": "http://example.com/trello/webhook-callback?type=features",
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "id": "5673a0ac6ab60af7ec3a706b",
    "description": "Bugs Board",
    "idModel": "541ebcf34c03910922ff0fc3",
    "callbackURL": "http://example.com/trello/webhook-callback?type=bugs",
    "active": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see a list of webhooks by using the token resource.

See here: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/token#get-1-tokens-token-webhooks

GET /1/tokens/[token]/webhooks

[token] equals [USER_TOKEN] if you created the webhook with the same token.

Answer (score 1):

I Tried all the answers, Non is working. then I found this endpoint : `https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/{{userToken}}/webhooks?key={{appKey}}` It's working fine, and it returns all the Trello webhooks. The data looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "*****427fb4***dsucd475*****",
        "description": "my test webhook",
        "idModel": "*****8df4sdy9u5gd6886f20c*****",
        "callbackURL": "https://******sum.ngrok-free.app/trello-webhook",
        "active": true,
        "consecutiveFailures": 0,
        "firstConsecutiveFailDate": null
    }
]
```